# How to capture full screenshot in Chrome using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using AShot library to capture full screenshot in Chrome but still its not working. Its overlapping images.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: Facing the same issue. Trying to get some solutions online.

Answer (score 0):

A normal FileUtils API is not working?

Try this,
`String page = "Page Name";
    File screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(screenShot, new File(page)); 
    }`

The driver will be ChromeDriver. Let me know if this helps!